# Using "this" to get class instance within companion scope in kotlin

Tags: android, kotlin, companion-object

Hi i was trying to access the parent class instance from its companion scope in (android studio) Kotlin, like

```
class A{

    companion object{
        val class_instance = this@A
    }
}
```

but it doesn't work, and it does outside the scope of Companion.
is there any way to get it done, if not why?

thanks in advance.

Comment: Companion is a "static singleton" so there's no instance to refer to. See https://kotlinlang.org/docs/object-declarations.html#object-declarations-overview

Comment: thanks, it really helped me.being new to Kotlin,i wasn't  really been thinking about the instance creation issues. i just wanted to have a default copy of  its instance accessible to any class without much overhead.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It should be somewhat rare for a class to need a default instance, but it can make sense in certain scenarios. The standard library's Random class has a default instance, and they do this by making its companion object a subclass of Random itself.

Cases where it makes sense might be for abstract classes that can have customized subclasses, but have a default implementation that is commonly adequate for most needs.

So for instance, you could make A's companion object a subclass of A like this:

```
abstract class A {
    abstract fun saySomething()

    companion object: A() {
        override fun saySomething() = println("Hello world")
    }
}
```